# Как верстать элемент нестандартной формы?

Tags: html, css

В макете есть вот такой элемент со стрелкой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно интересует верстка самой стрелки. Мне на ум приходят только полигоны и размещение объекта картинкой. Как лучше и правильнее верстать в данном случае?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например так:

```css
.btn {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #41738c;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 52px;
  line-height: 52px;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  
  position: relative;
}

.btn:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
 border-top: 30px solid #41738c;
 border-left: 15px solid transparent;
 border-right: 15px solid transparent;
 height: 0;
 width: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -30px;  
}

.btn:before {
    content: 'v';
    display: block;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -15px;
    bottom: -25px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-family: cursive;  
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">вы смотрели</a>
```

Но лучше картинкой вставить, не будет проблем с браузерами.

Answer (score 2):

Еще как вариант

```css
.btn,
.btn:after{
  -webkit-transtion: 0.3s;
  transtion: 0.3s;
}
.btn{
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px 45px;
  background: #427289;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;  
}
.btn:after{
  content: '✔';
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 50%;  
  margin-left: -15px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 24px;
  background: #427289; 
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  -webkit-transform: perspective(1px) rotateX(-1deg);
  -ms-transform: perspective(1px) rotateX(-1deg);  
  transform: perspective(1px) rotateX(-1deg);  
  box-shadow: 0 4px 2px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.25); 
}
.btn:hover{
  background: #f00;
}
.btn:hover:after{
  background: #f00;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 4px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="btn">Button</a>
```

Comment: Класс, так даже гораздо лучше моего варианта.